# Need Help with Redirection Un-subscribe from this thread

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I need some help with redirection.

I want to redirect a url as shown in the address bar as below:

> http://cricruns.com/venue/india/M.A.-Chidambaram

To a redirected url as below:

> http://cricruns.com/index.php/venue/stadium?name=M.A.-Chidambaram&tournament=World-Cup-2011

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you not tried the CodeIgniter User Guide?

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

> **redirect()**
>
> Does a "header redirect" to the URI
>   specified. If you specify the full
>   site URL that link will be build, but
>   for local links simply providing the
>   URI segments to the controller you
>   want to direct to will create the
>   link. The function will build the URL
>   based on your config file values.
>
> The optional second parameter allows
>   you to choose between the "location"
>   method (default) or the "refresh"
>   method. Location is faster, but on
>   Windows servers it can sometimes be a
>   problem. The optional third parameter
>   allows you to send a specific HTTP
>   Response Code - this could be used for
>   example to create 301 redirects for
>   search engine purposes. The default
>   Response Code is 302. The third
>   parameter is only available with
>   'location' redirects, and not
>   'refresh'.

Example:

```
if ($logged_in == FALSE)
{
     redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
}

// with 301 redirect
redirect('/article/13', 'location', 301);
```